# Unhandled Promise rejection: push.on is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using Ionic 2.

I get this Typescrpt **error** when trying to set up Push Notifications. I have copied this sample code from a tutorial, so would have expected it to work. I must have something wrong. Any ideas please:

> ```
> Unhandled Promise rejection: push.on is not a function ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value:
> TypeError: push.on is not a function
>
>
> push.on('registration', function (data) {
> ```

**typescript**

```
import { Push } from 'ionic-native';
```

.
.

```
  pushNotifications(): void {

    var push = Push.init({
      android: {
        vibrate: true,
        sound: true,
        senderID: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      },
      ios: {
        alert: "true",
        badge: true,
        sound: 'false'
      },
      windows: {}
    });

    push.on('registration', (data) => {
      console.log(data.registrationId);
      alert(data.registrationId.toString());
    });
    push.on('notification', (data) => {
      console.log(data);
      alert("Hi, Am a push notification");
    });
    push.on('error', (e) => {
      console.log(e.message);
    });

  }
```

Comment: Tried the following with the same error:     `push.on('registration', function (data) {
      console.log('++++++++++++++++++++++ FIRE ON!!');
      alert(data);
    });`

Comment: Glad im not the only one. Have you any resolution for this yet?

Comment: Not yet.  I have moved onto some other work in the mean time while I try figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to check if 'window.cordova' is available before using the plugin. Are you actually testing on a device or in browser? Cordova is not available within browser.

EDIT
To make sure your code editor knowns what 'window.cordova' is, make sure you installed cordova typings.

```
npm install typings -g
typings install dt~cordova --save --global
```